# Sorting Scenes in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

So I'm not sure what to call it, but its that bar on the left in Storyboard Editor in Xcode that displays all of the different scenes.  I love using storyboards, but my biggest pet peeve with them is that the scenes are organized in that list in an utterly random fashion.  Every time I add a new view controller to the storyboard it gets inserted into a seemingly random place on the list.  Two nearby views are not at all nearby in the scene listing.

So my question is this: Is it possible to reorder the scenes in that view, or to force some kind of sorting?

Comment: Seconded. Could be it's not possible, in which case filing an enhancement request radar issue with Apple sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the xml version ( "Open As"->"Source Code") of the Storyboard. Not sexy but works

Comment: Works like a charm and it's in fact quite easy using the `<!--` comments as guidance :)