# xcode 7.3 How to reorder scenes in the storyboard outline hierarchy?

Tags: storyboard, xcode7

Is there any way to reorder the scenes that appear in the hierarchical document outline panel for the storyboard? I have tried these routes without success: click drag, shift/opt/cmd click drags, right click submenu "move up" (there is no submenu).

The scenes on my screen are not even ordered alphabetically -- when I renamed some to try to change sort order by naming, that failed too. Thanks.

Comment: click-drag works for me. Getting it to land where I want is sometimes a challenge (I have to target the item I want to be above) EDIT - sorry, this works for objects inside a scene, but not for re-organizing the scenes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710641/sorting-scenes-in-xcode-interface-builder

Comment: @OldUgly, click-drag didn't work for me.  I guessed a number of modifier key-click combinations and none of them worked for me.  (I'm using Xcode 7.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Drag your Storyboard file to a text editor (SublimeText, Visual Studio Code, etc) and you will be able to modify the XML file directly. You should see something like this:

```
<scenes>
    <!--Navigation Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="xxx-xx-111">
       ...
    </scene>
    <!--Main-->
    <scene sceneID="xxx-xx-222">
       ...
    </scene>
</scenes>
```

Here you can reorder the **scene** nodes as you please. Changes will update as soon as you refocus Xcode (no need to restart or close the project).